# rails remote form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rjs, remote-forms

$("#wall_add").html("<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => "walls/form") ) %>");

display me

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/walls" class="new_wall" id="new_wall" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="9QBC/0uUIH2xJdZBcvTZb9Nsm1kL2hFipQq6NUdmCzU=" /></div> <div class="field"> <label for="wall_content">Content</label><br /> <textarea cols="40" id="wall_content" name="wall[content]" rows="20"></textarea> </div> <div class="actions"> <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Wall" /> </div> <input id="recipient" name="recipient" type="hidden" value="2" /> </form>
```

as text but not as html elements, http://deeflow.com/changer/remote.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call html_safe

```
$("#wall_add").html("<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => "walls/form").html_safe ) %>");
```

Comment: unfortunately, it's same result :(

Comment: what about also calling `html_safe` on the `escape_javascript`? Do you have an <pre> tags in your HTML document?

Comment: Oh, thank you! `$("#wall_add").html("<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => "walls/form") ).html_safe %>");` - is correct :)